# Using loop to bind click event over several elements not working in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a map of messages 
say:

```
var Mapping = {
"notnow": 2,
"expensive": 3,
"not_worth_it": 4
}
```

i have a bunch of html elements (lets say divs with the same name)
so

```
<div id="notnow"></div>
```

,etc

now i want to attach a click handler to each of them,
i run a loop as shown below

```
function setThemUp(){
   for(var item in Mapping)
   {
      $("#" + item).bind('click', function () {
      Apply(Mapping[item]); });
   }
}
```

But for some reason all of them seem to get bound to "not_worth_it":4. Not to their respective values.

I'm using Jquery 1.5.

Can someone please explain why this might be happening?

My guess is that instead of the Mapping[item] being resolved to their values, it's being passed as a reference or something, that's why since the value of item eventually points to "not worth it" all of them call the function with that value itself. Any way in which i could overcome them.

Hard coding each of them as

```
  $("#notnow").bind('click', function () {
      Apply(Mapping["notnow"]); });
  $("#expensive").bind('click', function () {
      Apply(Mapping["expensive"]); });
  $("#not_worth_it").bind('click', function () {
      Apply(Mapping["not_worth_it"]); });
```

does work, but i would prefer an elegant solution with a loop.

**Answer**

i went with the closure solution

```
function setThemUp(){
   for(var item in Mapping)
   {
       $("#" + item).bind('click', (function () {
            return function(temp) {
                 Apply(Mapping[temp]); };
            })(item));
       }
   }
```

Reasons being , this was more of a why the loop didn't work rather than about optimization of the jquery , since this was afterall a representative example, not my actual code, and this was an elegant solution to that problem.

Comment: Are you inserting elements dynamically?

Comment: You could just reference `Mapping[this.id]` in each of your click handlers. Also, it'd probably be better to give them all a class name so you can simplify the binding even further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic case of *scope* issues: you're referencing the variable `item` in each of your bound handlers. The variable `item` changes, though -> it's being assigned all properties of the `Mapping` object literal, the last one being `not_worth_it`.

Creating a closure might help, to preserve the state of `item` for each callback:

```
for(var item in Mapping)
{
   $("#" + item).bind('click', (function(currentItem)
   {//IIFE, pass item as argument---------/
        return function ()
        {//return function, \/ access to closure scope
            Apply(Mapping[currentItem]);
         };
    }(item)););
}
```

But this seems to be somewhat overkill, why not simply delegate the event, and use `Mapping[$(this).attr('id')]`?

Comment: I can't use $(this).attr('id') because the actual ids are a lot more convoluted that what is shown here, they need some processing, infact you can forget the ids all together, im more interested in the fact that the state of item is being preserved and that Mapping[item] is processed at the time of the event instead of the parameters being resolved when i bind them itself.

Comment: @BrijeshBharadwaj Well this answer solves your problem. Notice how the function passed to `bind` is executed immediately, and inside it returns the actual function to be executed when the item is clicked. This way, the state of the `item` variable is kept accurate per event

Comment: @BrijeshBharadwaj: you might want to think about using some data attribute to set the `Mapping` values, and delegate. After all, it's the most efficient way: one listener, one handler, all events. If not, a closure is what you need: the _value_ of `item` is being passed to an IIFE, which returns the handler. The scope of the IIFE is not GC'ed and so the handler still has access to the _value `item` HAD when the function was created_

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving to this form:

Add the class `mapped` to your mapping divs.

HTML

```
<div id="notnow" class="mapped"></div>
```

JS

```
function setThemUp(){
    $('.mapped').bind('click', function () {
        Apply(Mapping[this.id]); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you need to write:

```
for (var item in Mapping)
```

rather than foreach.